# collect the user input when make a call using Twilio API in c#?

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml, twilio-click-to-call

I tried the above approach, but I am not able to get response. I made call through "Twilio.Rest.Api.V2010.Account.CallResource.Create" method using c#. but I didn't get any option to get gather response using API. Gather is property/method of voice response. Can you please suggest me that How can we relate voice response with current call?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you create a call using the Twilio API, you need to provide a URL. When the call connects, Twilio will send a [webhook (HTTP) request](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/webhooks) to that URL to find out what to do next with the call.

[image: An example of Twilio making a webhook request]

Your application then needs to respond with [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml), which is a subset of XML, that gives instructions for the next steps with the call. In order to take user input, you need to return [`<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather) as part of that TwiML response.

I recommend that you take a look through this tutorial on [how to gather user input in a Twilio call using C#](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-gather-user-input-via-keypad-csharp) and ask further questions here if you have any more problems.